# Enable textbox and select using radiobutton in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

following my post awhile ago, this is my code for textbox and select to enable them using radiobuttons.

```
    <!-- Student Filter List-->
    <div class="studentfilter" style="display:inline-block; border: 2px solid black; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto; width: 400px;">
        <h2>Student Filter</h2>
        <br />
        <div style="display: inline-block">
            <input type="radio" id="rad1" onclick="Radiobutton()"/>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search ID" id="searchid" runat="server" class="form-control" style="width: 50%; display: inline-block" disabled />
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block">
            <input type="radio" id="rad2" onclick="Radiobutton()"/>
            <select class="form-control" runat="server" id="Year" style="width: 91%; display: inline-block" disabled>
                <option value="yearselected12" selected disabled>Filter by Year(student)</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            </select><br />
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block">
            <input type="radio" id="rad3" onclick="Radiobutton()" />
            <select class="form-control" runat="server" id="YearFrom" style="width: 49%; display: inline-block" disabled>
                <option value="yearfrom1" selected disabled>Year From</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>

            <select class="form-control" runat="server" id="YearTo" style="width: 42%; display: inline-block" disabled>
                <option value="yearto2" selected disabled>Year To</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
            </select>
        </div><br />
        <button type="button" runat="server" onserverclick="Allstudent_Click" id="ListofStudent" class="btn btn-primary">View Student</button>
        <button type="button" runat="server" onserverclick="Clear_Click" id="clearfilter" class="btn btn-default">Clear</button>
        <br />
        <label style="visibility:hidden;">asd</label>
    </div>
```

And this is my javascript code for the radiobutton.

```
<script>
    function Radiobutton() {
        if (document.getElementById('rad1').checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("searchid").disabled = false;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("searchid").disabled = true;
        }

        if(document.getElementById('rad2').checked == true)
        {
            document.getElementById("Year").disabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("Year").disabled = true;
        }

        if (document.getElementById('rad3').checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("YearFrom").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("YearTo").disabled = false;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("YearFrom").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("YearTo").disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

When I click one of the radiobutton for each they will enabled all the textbox and select. How do I make it my radiobutton to enable only one radiobutton and if I enable another one the other radiobutton is uncheck and the input tag is disabled and so on?

Comment: Give the radios the same name. That is how they work. If you save the current enabled one you can disable it in the click

Comment: `<input type="radio" id="rad1" onclick="Radiobutton()"/>` or `<input type="radio" id="rad3" onclick="Radiobutton()" />` you haven't mentioned name attribute tag. Add a **name** attribute and give all three radio button same name, this will create a group and when once is checked the other one is unchecked automatically.

Comment: @mplungjan It work! thank you for the reminder, just a minor error there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question is: How do set up a radiobutton in html? You need to define the name property on each of them. And make sure it is the same.

```
<input type="radio" name="radiobuttonlistname" id="rad1" onclick="Radiobutton()"/>
<input type="radio" name="radiobuttonlistname" id="rad2" onclick="Radiobutton()"/>
<input type="radio" name="radiobuttonlistname" id="rad3" onclick="Radiobutton()" />
```

And to answer your second question. The javascript is correct and seems to work for me.

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ldzdjh9/)

Comment: Oh great thanks!, one more question sir, How do I revise my code when I search the id section the page loads right, how do I make my radiobutton to stay as it is when you last click it? Example : I click the 2nd radiobutton(The page loads) after its done the "filteryear" section is enabled.